# Is there any way to use generator and open a file?

Tags: python, json, file, discord.py, valueerror

I'm currently working on a discord.py bot, looking for using generators more often in my code.
But I'm having an error when I try to initialize an object method with an output generator.
Here is what I've tried to do:

```
def get_language_config(member: Member):
    [role] = [role.name for role in member.roles if role.name in LANGS]
    return LANGS_TO_CONFIG[role]


@client.command(name="ip")
async def ip_command(ctx):
    sender = ctx.author
    translation = get_language_config(sender)
    data = Data(translation).read("langs")["IP_COMMAND"] # Here is the line that seems raise a problem.
    embed = BaseEmbed(title=data["title"], description=data["description"])
    embed.add_field(name=data["field_1"][0], value=data["field_1"][1])
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=BaseEmbed.BASIC_FILE)
```

Here is the Data() object class:

```
import json


class Data:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def update(self, key, value):
        with open("data/config.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json_data = json.load(file)
            json_data[self.data][key] = value
        with open("data/config.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(json_data, file, indent=2)

    def read(self, file: str):
        with open("data/%s.json" % file, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
        return data[self.data]
```

The output error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

P.S.: I'm sorry for my speaking language (I'm french) and it is the first time I post anything on the web-site.

Comment: What I'm sure to is that he error is from the generator element returning:
Because it works if I do ```print(Data("EN").read("langs")["IP_COMMAND"])```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a closed file,
Try to open it with:

```
with open("YOUR_FILE", "r") as file:
    data = Data(translation).read("file")["IP_COMMAND"]
```

Comment: Hello, yes but I already use this method (read()) in other part of my code and this works perfetly

Comment: It is maybe because of the return statement ?

Comment: Thats the problem, you use it everywhere else but here: data = Data(translation).read("langs")["IP_COMMAND"]  and that is the problem, the file if NOT open, your line with open() automatically closes the file after you do your things with it